# Go compile error?

Tags: go, proxy, compilation, compiler-errors, cuttle

I'm trying to compile [a fork of cuttle](https://github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle) that merges [this pull request](https://github.com/mrkschan/cuttle/pull/17)

by running

```
# GOPATH=`pwd` /usr/local/go/bin/go get github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle
# github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle
src/github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle/main.go:103: zone.GetController(r.URL.Host, r.URL.Path).Acquire() used as value
```

[Here is](https://github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle/blob/master/main.go#L103) the offending line

I have no experience with Go. Is that an error? It doesn't seem to update the compiled binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the source code [here](https://github.com/mrkschan/cuttle/blob/master/cuttle/limitcontrol.go#L40):

```
// Acquire permission from NoopControl.
// Permission is granted immediately since it does not perform any rate limit.
func (c *NoopControl) Acquire() {
    log.Debugf("NoopControl[%s]: Seeking permission.", c.Label)
    log.Debugf("NoopControl[%s]: Granted permission.", c.Label)
}
```

There is **NO return value** of `func (c *NoopControl) Acquire()`.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong version of the code. It does return a bool in the patched version: https://github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle/blob/master/cuttle/limitcontrol.go

Comment: @Andres Well, u should `go update` the version of your local code. check this https://github.com/andresdouglas/cuttle/blob/master/main.go#L14 (There is a 404).

Comment: Excellent catch! let me try that